# Wordpress utilize JSON

Tags: json, wordpress, api, getjson

I'm having difficulties utilizing a JSON feed; I'm trying to echo different parts of each entry (eg. comment & completion_date). I'm very new with JSON feeds and am obviously a bit lost.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I'm trying to use the following JSON feed: http://www.guildquality.com/ws/wpwidget.php?mp=http://www.guildquality.com/cr/Renewal-by-Andersen-Las-Vegas-Phoenix/LE9647224674EGQ/.

A foreach loop would be perfect, I just don't get how to abstract the info from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('url');
$json_array = json_decode( $json_string, TRUE );

print '<pre>';
print_r( $json_array );
```

There are a couple of different ways to do this, but the basics are... Get the json string from source, decode it ( the TRUE in the json decode will decode it into an associative array ) and then you should be able to treat it like any array you want to. Good Luck.